# How to locate the private key of a certificate in Windows

Tags: x509certificate

I want to locate the private key of a certificate in the current user certificate store in Windows. Does anyone know where the private key is saved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This article describes where private keys are stored on a filesystem: [Key Storage and Retrieval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204778(v=vs.85).aspx)

To determine exact file name, run the following command in the Command Prompt:

```
certutil -user -store my "<SerialNumber>"
```

where `<SerialNumber>` is the serial number of the target certificate. If certificate contains private key, there will be `Unique Container Name` field which contains file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the certificates in the Microsoft Management Console (MMC). See here a guide with some steps:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967(v=vs.110).aspx